# Using \subfloat to represent subfigures side by side

Tags: positioning, subfloats

I am using `\subfloat` inside a table (`tabular`) to represent 6 images in across both columns of a two column document, as shown below. I am having no error message, but the images this figure and all the others after it won't appear in the pdf file.

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/A.pdf}} & 
\subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/Bt.pdf}} &
\subfloat[c]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/C.pdf}} \\
\subfloat[d]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/D.pdf}} &
\subfloat[e]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/E.pdf}} &
\subfloat[f]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/F.pdf}}\\
\subfloat[g]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/G.pdf}} &
\subfloat[h]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/H.pdf}} &
\subfloat[i]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/I.pdf}} 
\end{tabular}
\caption[]{Description}
\label{fig:ABC}
\end{figure*}
```

I've verified that if I leave only 3 images it will appear when I generate the PDF. So this might be a problem related to the width of figure relative to the page width.

I've tried to use `subfigure` but it didn't worked either. I've tried changing the maximum number of figures in the `.tex` document but it didn't helped.

I would appreciate some solution that would allow me to put 6 images in the same figure in a two column document, each one with a capture bellow it.

Edit 1:
Follows a minimal example that reproduces my problem:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}% twocolumn

\journalname{Journal}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}

\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

\title{X}

\author{ author }

\maketitle

\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{images/a1.pdf}} &
  \subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{images/b1.pdf}} &
  \subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{images/c1.pdf}} \\
  \subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{images/d1.pdf}} &
  \subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{images/e1.pdf}} & 
  \subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{images/f1.pdf}} 
  \end{tabular}
\caption[]{Caption}
\label{fig:per}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{images/a.pdf}} & 
\subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{images/b.pdf}} &
\subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{images/c.pdf}} \\
\subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{images/d.pdf}} &
\subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{images/e.pdf}} &
\subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{images/f.pdf}}\\
\subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{images/g.pdf}} &
\subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{images/h.pdf}} &
\subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{images/i.pdf}} 
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[trim=0cm 0cm 0cm 11cm, clip=true, width=0.35\textwidth]{images/legend.pdf}} 
\end{tabular}
\caption[]{Caption}
\label{fig:rep}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

The result of compiling this is a page with the name of the journal, an x as title and author written bellow. No images show up.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting the minimal version of the code, I've started eliminating packages to see if anything would happen. Turns out the problem was with \usepackage{stfloats}.
After commenting this line all the images appear just the way they should.

Answer (score 2):

There's a missing closing square bracket square in the (first) optional argument for `\subfloat` in the line

```
\subfloat[f{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/F.pdf}}\\
```

it should be

```
\subfloat[f]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/F.pdf}}\\
```

The missing brace, however, triggers an error message and in your question you said no errors were produced?

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
\subfloat[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/A.pdf}} & 
\subfloat[b]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/Bt.pdf}} &
\subfloat[c]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/C.pdf}} \\
\subfloat[d]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/D.pdf}} &
\subfloat[e]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/E.pdf}} &
\subfloat[f]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/F.pdf}}\\
\subfloat[g]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/G.pdf}} &
\subfloat[h]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/H.pdf}} &
\subfloat[i]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{images/I.pdf}} 
\end{tabular}
\caption[]{Description}
\label{fig:ABC}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

The output:

[image]

Comment: The lack of the square bracket is not the problem (it was a mistake of mine when I inserted the code here).

Comment: @Edien then, please complete your code snippet to a *complete* yet minimal document illustrating the problem and allowing us to reproduce it. Otherwise, no effective help can be provided.

Comment: My problem is different: I could make all the images show exactly how i wanted for a given period of time. I've tried to change the width of a figure* above this one, which resulted in this figure and all the others that follow disappearing. So I changed the width back, since it was not fundamental. Then I added some text, and this figure and all the others that follow disappeared again. I am almost sure this is related to the number of images, since if I comment some images on a figure* above this one (with same format that I described above) all the images will appear again in the pdf.

Comment: @Edien disappeared or were moved to another location (typically the end of the document)?

Comment: I've checked, the figure is not at the end of the document. I'll try to post an example that recreates the problem in a while.

Comment: @Edien OK. Thanks. Let me know once you've done so. Before that, as a last test, try removing `[h]` from `\begin{figure}[h]`.